# Unable to get sequence number

Tags: horizon, python-sdk

I am trying to create a transaction op and I am not being able to get the sequence number. I tried on [Stellar lab](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#txbuilder?params=eyJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7InNvdXJjZUFjY291bnQiOiJHQUxTSUxEN1NYSUVDM0o1QjVLM0lKSklRQ1hYMlpJMlo2RFpNRkVQRVlESTZTQlc2SUxMNVI3ViJ9fQ%3D%3D&network=) but it did not work. What's wrong? Below is my code:

```
# print('Transferring fund to {}'.format(customer_account))
    print('Transferring fund to {}'.format(destination_account))
    response = None
    is_transferred = True

    try:
        # Now create Payment Op
        op = Payment({
            'source': source_account,
            'destination': destination_account,
            'asset': asset_object,
            'amount': str(amount)
        })
        msg = TextMemo('REF ID: {}'.format(refund_code))

        # Getting the next sequence of the address
        sequence = horizon.account(source_account).get('sequence')

        # construct Tx
        tx = Transaction(
            source=source_account,
            opts={
                'sequence': sequence,
                'memo': msg,
                'operations': [
                    op,
                ],
            },
        )
```

**Update**

I notice the issue is when the coin is RETURNED BACK to the issuer. No Sequence number issue with the issuer sends coin to the requestor.

Comment: What is the `source_account` object?

Comment: @RichardDunn It is a string variable of Customer Address, in case it is `GALSILD7SXIEC3J5B5K3IJJIQCXX2ZI2Z6DZMFEPEYDI6SBW6ILL5R7V`

Comment: @RichardDunn ISSUER is `GBRLFJMK4G3K24YVGTXIHOWJHKRL6QHC4UB4OEOCGDLEEW3WE4G7POVZ`

Comment: @RichardDunn It seems accounts are expired https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GALSILD7SXIEC3J5B5K3IJJIQCXX2ZI2Z6DZMFEPEYDI6SBW6ILL5R7V

Comment: When did you last use those accounts? The testnet gets reset every 3 months now.

Comment: Just a month back

Comment: The testnet was wiped about 2-3 weeks ago.

Comment: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/test-net.html

Comment: @RichardDunn was it not scheduled for April?

Comment: February 27th, 2019 was the last one, as per the link.